# Tic tac toe Java GUI project - end message not popping up

Tags: java, swing, awt, tic-tac-toe

I just finished my first two semesters of java classes at my college. I am very excited to learn and am going back and trying to fix some of my projects as a learning experience. In this assignment, I had to create a tic-tac-toe game. I managed to get everything working that the assignment required, but I'm having issues with figuring out a stalemate. 
I made 2 2D arrays, one of JButtons and one of an object that represents a tic tac toe object that has basic get/set methods for a char(X or O) and a boolean to indicated if it is occupied.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                try{
                    if(player_array[i][j].getOccupied()){
                        throw new CellTakenException("Cell taken, try another.");
                    }
                    else {
                        if(e.getSource()==button_array[i][j]){
                            move_num++;
                            if(move_num%2!=0){
                                player_array[i][j].setOccupid(true);
                                player_array[i][j].setChar('X');
                                button_array[i][j].setText("X");
                                if(gameWon()){
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pane,button_array[i][j].getText()+" wins!");
                                }
                            }
                            else if(move_num%2==0){
                                player_array[i][j].setOccupid(true);
                                player_array[i][j].setChar('O');
                                button_array[i][j].setText("O");
                                if(gameWon()){
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pane,button_array[i][j].getText()+" wins!");
                                }
                            }
                            else if(move_num==9){
                                if(boardFull()){
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pane,"Game over. No Winners.");
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
                catch(CellTakenException c){
                    c.getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I initially tried just using the move_num value to check if it was over, but that wasn't working so I added a boolean called boardFull() that checks if every button has been pressed and the occupied boolean for the tic tac toe object.

```
public boolean boardFull(){
  int cellTaken=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(button_array[i][j].getModel().isPressed()&&player_array[i][j].getOccupied()){
                cellTaken++;
                }
            }
        }
    return cellTaken==9;
}
```

I can't figure out why stalemate message doesn't pop up. Does anyone know why this is the case/what I could do to fix it?

Comment: I'd guess that whichever of `move_num%2!=0` or `move_num%2==0` is `true`, prevents the other `else if` from ever happening.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check **boardFull()** after if **gameWon()**. Because incase of your last move went to any "X" or "O". It will not reach to your "Game over. No Winners." case.

```
if(gameWon()){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pane,button_array[i][j].getText()+" wins!");
}
elseif(boardFull()){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pane,"Game over. No Winners.");
}
```

try to put this condition in both of "X" and "O".
I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This unfortunately doesn't work, but I think there are some errors in my logic in the gameWon() method that prevent the stalemate message from popping up. I think your suggestion should work once I fix that.

Comment: Could you show me your gameWon() method? Maybe we can find out together.